# Visual Studio Add-in - How do I create an Installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I have made a Visual Studio Add-in as part of a project I'm working on using web services.

When I created the new Add-in project in visual studio it generated all the code required and installed the blank add-in on my pc (I assume).

Since this is a large project we are using svn to manage the code base and once I had done some of the work on the Add-in I commited it, then checked it out on a different pc and attempted to run it.

However on the other pc when I run the add-in in debug mode, the tools entry for the add-in is not present and I can't run the add-in.

Am I right in assuming that when I created the project on the other pc it installed the plugin as well? And does that mean that I will need to create an installer for any other pcs I wish to use?

Obviously at some point I intend on making an installer anyway but not untill after the development of the addin is complete.

Comment: Which version of VS? In VS2010 there may be better options. VS addin installers are evil.

Comment: VS2008, I would love for it to be 2010 but its not lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I fixed my issue.

after doing some googling into a different issue I was having I stumbled apon the answer to my installer issue.

When the visual studio Add-in wizard creates your blank add-in it creates **two** xml files with the .Addin extension.

One of these is saved locally along with your project the other is copied to whatever path that copy of visual studio uses for its add-in folder.

So by copying the .addin file to the correct location on my other pc I can now run the Addin in both locations.

Comment: I made the same approach in my code formatting addin for assisting in stylecop compliance and I've had no issues.  Just make sure the .Addin file contains the path to where you install the addin files.